# APIGateway CORS enabled and Lambda proxy integration enabled but still running into CORS issues

Tags: api, cors, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have the following CDK code for my API Gateway

```
    this.restAPI = new RestApi(this, name, {
        cloudWatchRole: true,
        domainName: {
            domainName: props.recordName,
            certificate: props.cert,
            endpointType: EndpointType.REGIONAL,
            securityPolicy: SecurityPolicy.TLS_1_2
        },
        defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
            allowOrigins: Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
            allowMethods: ['OPTIONS', 'POST', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT', 'PATCH'],
            allowHeaders: Cors.DEFAULT_HEADERS,
            maxAge: Duration.seconds(86400)
        }
    });
```

which results in this

[image]

But I'm still running into this error:

```
/#/actors:1 Access to fetch at 'https://web-api.alpha.myapp.com/api/v1/actors?page=1' from origin 'https://alpha.myapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

But if you look at my Access-Control-Allow-Origin it's set to '*'. So I'm not sure what I'm missing.

And just to validate I do have Lambda Proxy integration turned on [image]

Comment: Is there a reason why the values in the UI are wrapped in single quotes? Are they generated by CDK? Could you try removing them and see what happens then?

Comment: That's just how CDK did it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my lambda that returns the GET content actually has to include the relevant CORS headers. It's not enough to just turn on CORS support on API Gateway.